# Benchmarking library usable from C#

Tags: c#, windows, benchmarking

I am wanting to conduct benchmark tests on a couple of servers that I manage and would like to be able to set up my own scenarios and order of events/ automation.

So I'm wondering if there are any libraries that can be used to perform benchmarking of different aspects of a windows computer such as CPU, Disk IO, and RAM.

**Update 1**:
Since there seems to be no available libraries for doing this I'll also accept answers pointing to examples or guides of how one can test CPU, Disk and Memory performance with C#.

**Update 2** are there any good libraries for this in any language?

Comment: I'd recommend reading this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8590/An-Introduction-To-Performance-Counters, a good intro to the [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) class which I think you'll find useful.

Comment: That seems interesting but maybe not exactly what I'm looking for. The examples on codeproject seem to be about measuring current performance not about taking the system to its max and seeing what it can do. Perhaps I can use it together with some code that takes the cpu / disk / memory to its limits and see what it gets too.

Comment: Very interesting question. Would be awesome if you could summerise your findings and answer here :). Ahmm with c# you aim only for Windows Server?

Comment: My primary target is for windows server and I'm very familiar with C#.. but I dont have any problem with Java if there is a good library available for it.

Comment: So far I've written a simple test program that creates massive amounts of threads (64 threads per core) that each run a CPU and disk heavy task repeatedly as fast as they can. I then calculate a score based on the total amount of tasks completed in a given amount of time. Crude, but gives me a basic comparison between servers. Thinking this can be done better without making it all from scratch ;)

Comment: I am not sure whether C# is the perfect language (or rather, .Net the runtime) for benchmarking. It is interrupted by the GC which will influence testing for bare metal perforance. However you of course can test for how a .Net app will behave on the benchmarked machine.

Comment: @Dykam yeah you have a good point there. Not sure how much this will influence the results. Also my primary purpose is to compare two different setups to each other so as long as all test are run under the same circumstances (ie using .net) the comparison between two servers should still reveal which has the better overall performance in %.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this open-source framework [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/BenchmarkDotNet) for CPU benchmarking. It include Stopwatch using, GC pre-call, warmup, set priority of process, thred, ProcessorAffinity-mask, api for benchmark competitions and nice console output with results.

Answer (score 1):

This might be outside the scope, however I was looking for something similar at the unit test level and found [this MSDN topic about Creating and Editing Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728098%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: This seems like it can be used for hammering an application with different requests.. so in theory I could probably saturate my cpu /disk / ram if I run the test towards code that uses those types of resources.. Not exactly what I had in mind, but thank you for the tip.

Comment: @wokawaka In the server environment, you don't just throw stuff at the server and see how it handles. You write your program that performs the job you need done, you then hammer the program, and see ***where*** the slowdown is caused. If the slowdown is from a poorly optimized loop, you fix your code. If the slow down is from slow Disk I/O, you upgrade your disk I/O with faster drives. Think of it this way, your question is looking for "The Best" when you need to be looking for "The Best at doing whatever job I am going to give the server".

Comment: @wokawaka Thinking about my phrase more, i think I needs to be rephrased as "The equipment that will fulfill my needs for whatever job I am going to give the server". If you spend $15,000 on a [RAMSAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Memory_Systems) when a RAID 0 set up of a pair of $200 raptor disks would work fine, and you where my employee, you would not be my employee for long.